# image map dead in internet explorer 10

Tags: image, dictionary, internet-explorer-10

I need help with an image map! It seems they are not compatible with IE10. Although I have one on another site have made that works. But does anyone have any idea why this is not working? It was working then all the sudden after an update...stopped. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
       <img alt="" src="http:///www.elysiawright.com/asset/mapjennifer.png" width="665" height="413" usemap="#Map" style="border-width: 0px;border-style: solid;" />
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="516,147,522,142,524,145,575,137,581,143,579,153,585,161,577,167,575,171,520,183,515,147" href="http://www.allnaturalbeelievers.com/Pennsylvania.html" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="502,208,505,196,508,201,513,185,520,181,520,169,522,183,535,180,536,188,544,181,552,178,556,185,549,185,544,198,540,200,535,200,531,213,527,219,513,224,501,209" href="http://www.allnaturalbeelievers.com/WestVirginia.html" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="468,159,474,199,475,199,491,204,501,204,520,182,516,148,501,159,484,156,466,159" href="http://www.allnaturalbeelievers.com/Ohio_2.html" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="388,4,608,67" href="http://www.allnaturalbeelievers.com/distributorsignup.html" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="555,402,564,389,565,378,565,373,534,318,459,325,457,331,476,331,485,341,497,334,516,342,524,366,557,403" href="http://www.allnaturalbeelievers.com/Florida.html" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="472,199" href="#" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="435,222,459,217,471,203,466,157,436,162,433,220" href="http://www.allnaturalbeelievers.com/Indiana.html" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="496,230,582,220,576,210,573,201,564,189,560,186,557,184,549,184,548,198,538,200,530,218,513,226,506,223,495,228" href="http://www.allnaturalbeelievers.com/Virginia.html" target="#" />
    </map>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the third slash in the image URL and it works fine for me in IE10.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xeG7d/1/

**BAD**

```
<img alt="" src="http:///www.elysiawright.com/asset/mapjennifer.png" width="665" height="413" usemap="#Map" style="border-width: 0px;border-style: solid;" />
```

**GOOD**

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.elysiawright.com/asset/mapjennifer.png" width="665" height="413" usemap="#Map" style="border-width: 0px;border-style: solid;" />
```

The [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) catches this error, and is a valuable debugging tool for situations like this. However, I'll admit that despite the error I didn't catch the malformed URL right away.